# Jess plugin error on eclipse indigo

Tags: eclipse, jess

so my jess usually working fine but just today i got this error , it happen everytime i opened or added .clp file and it always show this kinda warning .

[image]

[image]

this whats written in the log file

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 2 0 2017-05-26 01:29:16.395
!MESSAGE The Java indexing could not index C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/lib/rt.jar|com/sun/media/sound/JDK13Services.class. This .class file doesn't follow the class file format specification. Please report this issue against the .class file vendor

i tried reinstall jess and eclipse but still the same result .

So if anyone know how to fix this please tell me

Comment: Very likely the 1.8 is something Indigo cannot handle - it was released when Java 1.6 was around and 1.7 coming up. -- Remove the 1.8 jars or better, upgrade Eclipse!

Comment: @laune thx for the response , i tried using jre 1.6 it still give me the same error

Comment: I don't think I recommended using Java 1.6. Did you move C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_112/ to some other place that isn't in the class path? Why is it there - did you upgrade to Java 8?

Comment: @laune i accidentally updated to JAVA 8 . yeah i tried moving jre1.8 to somewhere and it still give me the same problem

Comment: Really the very same error with the same path to the same jar file??? Did you get rid of all of the jars that came with 1.8? Do you have any .class compiled with that compiler?

Comment: @laune thx for the respond , it worked i just deleted all java associated file and reinstall jre 1.7